# How to receive incoming message on the twilio android client? Is there any way to receive sms/MMS on android client

Tags: java, android, twilio, ibm-cloud

I am developing an application in android (Twilio Android Client) using Twilio, which consumes the Rest API.

I can successfully send the SMS using the rest API. However, when someone replies to SMS/MMS, the server will get that message because Twilio will hit that URL.

But on the other hand, I don't understand how to update the client device when we receive an SMS/MMS using Twilio.

Is there any way to update or send the message (SMS/MMS) to the client device when a server receives an incoming message(SMS/MMS)?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a URL for SMS/MMS in your twilio number. Now, when the user replies to this number, this script in this URL will be executed. In this script, write code to forward SMS/MMS to your android device's phone number.

If you want to handle replies solely via your app, (ie, not by conventional SMS and MMS)  then store reply SMS and MMS in server. Then write an API in server to get these messages. Now write code in android to periodically query this API and retrieve these messages.

Comment: Yes, I configure the URL on the server for SMS/MMS in Twilio Number. It executes fine but I did not want to use query periodically on the android device. 
Is twilio provides any api or facility to send the SMS reply to android device by twilio.

Comment: No. Then you have to send the reply SMS via REST API to that android devices's phone number.

Comment: How we can send this reply to client device via rest API. Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: The above URL which you have mentioned in the previous comment, It is used for sending messages and what we have to do when we are getting replies for particular number.

Comment: A URL will be executed when you specify a SMS URL for your number. You'll get the message body and from numbers as request parameters. Assign these to variables. (say `$body`, `$from`). Then, in this file, write code to initiate outbound SMS. The body of the message should be `$body`. If you want to inform the sender's number, specify `$from` also in message body.